# Lebesgue measure of some sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, lebesgue-measure

Let $p(\mathbf{x})$ be a non-zero polynomial in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{x}]$. It is known that the affine variety $$ V = \{\mathbb{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:p(\mathbf{x}) =0 \}$$ has Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Now, consider the following set
$$ S_{\varepsilon} = \{\mathbb{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: |p(\mathbf{x})| \leq \varepsilon\},$$ with $\varepsilon > 0$.

1) What can be said about the Lebesgue measure of $S_{\varepsilon}$?

2) Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure. Is it true that $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \mu (S_{\varepsilon}) = \mu(V)=0$?

I just need some ideas to answer these questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: (2) may fail: consider the polynomial $p(x,y)=x-y$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ you have $\mu (S_{\varepsilon}) = \infty$. Anyway, if $\mu (S_{\varepsilon}) < \infty$ for some $\varepsilon$, then (2) is true.

Comment: @Crostul, I cannot see $\mu(S_{\varepsilon}) = \infty$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ when $p(x,y) = x-y$. For example, if $\varepsilon$ is a very small number, then $S_{\varepsilon}$ is a set of points closed to and in the straigth $x=y$. Compared to $\mathbb{R}^2$, it seems to be a very thin set. So, how can it be the measure infinity?

Comment: It is an infinite stripe of positive constant width. Hence it has infinite area.

Comment: @Crostul, I see. But, if $\mu$ is a probability measure, such that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^{n}) = 1$, can I say that (2) is true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, in the case that the measure is finite, then (2) is true. This is due to the theorem  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Measures_of_infinite_intersections_of_measurable_sets)